# Error in eval(expr envir enclos): could not find function

Tags: r, statistics

```
{r}
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=ntiles(carat), y=price)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    theme(legend.position="none") + 
    labs(title="")
```

I had these lines reporting:

> Error in eval(expr envir enclos): could not find function "ntiles" Calls ...unlist->lapply->eval.quoted->lapply->FUN->eval Execution halted`

I got my code from `show expression` in `mplot` so it worked fine in console, but it keeps giving me this error when I try to knit it. Can anyone help figuring out what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you using knitr here? What does `{r}` mean?

Comment: @RichardScriven I use rstudio, {r} is r chunk

Comment: So you're trying to create a document?  This might be relevant information.

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm trying to create a graph

Comment: If you are using `mosaic::ntiles` then you should put the `library` call above the code that expects it.